# Using verbs in class names

Tags: language-agnostic

I'm reading Robert C. Martins book Clean Code. He writes about a convention not using verbs in class names.

The project I'm currently working on we need to validate and process some xml, so I created something like this

```
public class XmlProcesser
{
public XmlProcesser(string filePathAndName)
{
}

public bool Validate()
{
}
}
```

But Uncle Bobs recommendation is not to use "Processor" in the class name.

But what should I call it? Xml is no good, because I'm using the .net class xml a lot in the code. I thought about XmlHandler but I guess that is worse than Processor since "handler" is something else for a programmer.

How do you do? Do you use verbs in your class names?

Comment: Processor isn't a verb, it a noun derived from the verb _to process_. At least in the german language in would be - beware, I am not a native english speaker.

Comment: Verbs are about actions.  Processing is the most general action so it doesn't convey a lot of info.  Perhaps you could find a bit more info if you described what the class does in more specific terms?

Comment: Ignoring the example for a bit (because it's not a good example of what you're trying to say), what is Uncle Bob's reasoning for not using verbs?

Comment: @drhirsch thats correct that Processor is not a verb, but the author of the book explicitly says not to use "Processor" in class names

Comment: @JeffFoster The class takes a path and file name and processes the xml. Then the user can validate the xml. The validation tells the user if all the necessary information is provided in the xml. He can also call GetPerson which returns the aggregated root of the domain that is populated from the xml.

Comment: @MrLister He doesn't explain very thoroughly. This is what he says:

"Classes and objects should have noun or noun phrase names like Customer, WikiPage, Account, and AddressParser. Avoid words like Manager, Processor, Data, or Info in the name of a class. A class name should not be a verb."

Comment: @FatAlbert I just don't agree with Robert C. Martins here. I do not see a different quality of the names between `AddressParser` and `XmlProcessor`. In general `Processor` might be somewhat more unspecific than `Parser`, because there is a lot which can be processed but can't be parsed. Maybe `XmlData` is more to your liking? But Data is very general too ;-)

Comment: @drhirsch Exactly. Martins may have a point with "Data" or "Info" being too generic, but other than that, I think we can safely ignore him. Or, does he mean that a one-word class name like "Processor" is not good, and it should read "AddressProcessor" to be OK in his eyes?

Comment: Thanks for your replies. I will continue to use the name XmlProcessor.

(Next time I ask a question I'll try and be more clear from the beginning.)

Answer (score 54, accepted):

Naming is important.  Heck, T.S. Eliot and Andrew Lloyd Webber made fortunes from *The Naming of Cats*.  But Martins' point isn't about not using verbs - it's about object-oriented thinking.  Classes are patterns for instantiating objects.  Objects are things.  Are similar things better described by their behaviors or by their names?

Am I a carnivore?  Yup.  But I also write programs.  Am I a programmer?  Yup.  But I also voted for Obama.  Am I an Obama supporter?  Yup.  But ...  In the end, I am a person.  More correctly, I am an instance of the class[1] `HomoSapiensSapiens`.  And `HomoSapiensSapiens` has many, many, MANY methods, all of which have verb-like names to them.  Like `HomoSapiensSapiens.EatBacon()`.  Like `HomoSapiensSapiens.WriteGoodCode()`.  Like `HomoSapiensSapiens.VoteDemocratic()`.  *etc.*

Martin's big point is that **if your classes are best named like verbs, you're thinking about your classes all wrong.**

[1] "class" in the OO meaning, not the Kingdom/Phylum/Class biological meaning.

Comment: This was an informative and thoughtful post, presented in an easy-to-understand way.  More of this!

Comment: Robert Martin shouldn't have used `AddressParser` to make that point then, because it is still a behavior. Bertrand Meyer regards classes that are defined as "performing" something as a danger signal of potentially improper abstraction, along with classes with a single exported routine (see red box at the end of [this page](https://archive.eiffel.com/doc/manuals/technology/oosc/finding/page.html)).

Comment: @Piovezan I agree.  One would more likely expect to have an `Address` object with a `Parse()` method.  Even Bob Martin isn't always right :-)

Comment: Actually I took Mr. Meyer's recommendations out of context. Those classes may be a bad idea if they lack a parameterized constructor and feature a single method. "Doer" classes with a command method but also a parameterized constructor (or a query method for that matter) may be acceptable abstractions according to him (example: the Observer class in the corresponding design pattern).

Comment: When you say *"Classes are patterns for instantiating objects. Objects are things..."*, you should have explicitly added *"Actions/methods of classes/objects should be verbs"*

Comment: Ok, but the idea behind inheritance is that the relationship is: Inherited Class "is a" Base Class. Mammal is an Animal, Cat is a Mammal, etc. 

So your base class is HomoSapiensSapiens. Would TallHomoSS or AsianHomoSS be valid inherited classes? Those are fairly inherent traits. What about AmericanHomoSS? RepublicanHomoSS? If those are ok then what about LawyerHomoSS? We're inching toward the specialization being something someone does, i.e. verblike. Is specializing by behavior essentially different from specializing by other traits (e.g. body type, ethnicity, nationality, job)?

Answer (score 14):

1. As mentioned in the comments: Processor is derived from a verb, not a verb. Therefore Processor is an Ok name for class.
2. XmlProcessor doesn't really tell you much about the class. Ok, it is dealing with xml, but what does it do? Validate it? Forward it? Parse it? So it is very likely that there is a way better name around the corner
3. Taking the SOLID principles seriously you often end up with classes like
   XmlProcessor{
       public void process(){ ... }
   }

or

```
CalvinTransmogrifier{
    public Calvin transmogrify(Calvin c){ ...}
}
```

At that point you kind of reached the border between OOP and Functional Programming. And one can make an argument that

```
Transmogrify{
    public Calvin do(Calvin c){ ... }
}
```

is an acceptable way to name things. If this is actually the case depends on your language of choice. E.g. in Scala if you can use 'apply' instead of 'do' and actually call the apply mothed like this

```
Transmogrify(new Calvin)
```

which at least I consider nicer then

```
Transmogrifier.do(new Calvin)
```

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, it's a bad habit to name a class with verbish words like "Processor".   What does the XMLProcessor you made actually process?   Hold that thought.  You said there's already a class named XML, otherwise you would use that.  The problem is exactly that frustration you felt having to come up with a different name.  The XML class is looking you right in the face, saying "I am XML, I am awesome, do not try to replace me, because I can process XML despite my short name.  Don't think for a moment that I can't "process" something, bucko. "  (if classes could talk and were annoying).
So, now, explain what your XMLProcessor class does that the standard XML class does not do.  That's the crux of what you are missing.  Perhaps you can extended the XML class to do whatever it is that the XMLProcessor does.  Or perhaps you can create a new class that derives from the XML class, and name it based on what it processes that the base XML class cannot.

For those that "disagree with Uncle Bob", that just means you don't understand.  It doesn't mean you are right.

Comment: It doesn't *necessarily* mean you're wrong though. But your point about perhaps extending the XML class instead is a good one.